# Render form with errors and file inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, nested-forms, simple-form

I have a form with nested attributes for attachments.

Everything seems to be working fine till the moment user submits the form with error on a field other than the attachments.

At the first submit of the form I re-render the form displaying the errors but the nested fields for the files he/she attached don't display their values, they are empty. Thus, when user fixes his/her error, the form submits with no attachments.

How should I handle this; I want when rendering the form with errors to have the file inputs with the previously submitted values. If you suggest another approach be my guest.

Sample code:

```
= simple_nested_form_for foo do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.fields_for :attachments do |af|
    = af.input :attached_file
  = f.submit 'Create'
```

Comment: After re-rendering, is the file input field empty as well? (I mean obviously empty to the user.)

Comment: @gg_s Yes, it's empty...

Comment: ...which results in no attachment, exactly as expected. What should happen instead? The question doesn't say, only "how should I implement this." Implement what?

Comment: @gg_s Thought it was clear, I edited my post.

Comment: Maybe you should think about an Ajax submit (`remote: true`), the serveurs responds with errors or not, and you "colorize" the wrong inputs? I think (not sure) that boostrap can do that nicely

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send image of file through ajax then u cant send it directly as ajax is used to send data to server without refreshing the current page it accepts less amount of data.

Other way to send file through ajax is to either hack or else the simple one use remotipart gem [remotipart](http://os.alfajango.com/remotipart/)